# GPG2 imported SSH `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256` key can't be set to [Authenticate]

Tags: gnupg

I've imported my existing keys into GnuPG agent (gpg2) using ssh-add and now trying to register them as subkeys of my primary GPG key as outlined in https://opensource.com/article/19/4/gpg-subkeys-ssh.

I see keys' keygrips in `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol`, I've already added Ed25519 key but the imported ECDSA key I'm trying to add only propose Encrypt purpose, and no Authentication, which makes it unsuitable for use as SSH key unless somehow overridden by the software.

Is this intentional or I don't understand something fundamental about GPG?

Comment: The title says "ECDH," but you say "ECDSA" in the question.  Which is it?

Comment: In SSH it is labeled as `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`.